# spans in an anchor in a single line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have all three spans within an anchor, inline. Not sure what is missing from the code:

```css
a.facebook-button {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  left: auto;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.fb-button-left {
  width: 40px;
}

.fb-button-right,
.fb-button-center,
.fb-button-left {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  background: url(../img/fb-button.png) left top no-repeat;
}

.fb-button-right {
  width: 6px;
  background-position: 100% -80px;
}

.fb-button-center {
  padding: 0 5px 0 8px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #6385ba;
  background-position: left -40px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

div.socialInvites {
  padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialInvites">
  <a href="main/facebook_request" class="facebook-button" id="facebookbutton">
    <span class="fb-button-left"></span>
    <span class="fb-button-center"><strong>Connect</strong> with <strong>Facebook</strong></span>
    <span class="fb-button-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear.

Comment: Spans inside anchor are coming with a line break. I want them in a single line.

Comment: Given the code you provided, they do all appear on the same line: http://jsfiddle.net/d4dYw/ -- the problem must be in some other piece of code.

Comment: Works fine in the fiddle I made http://jsfiddle.net/qn3MR/

Answer (score -1):

Please try adding the following:

`display:inline;`

Example:

```
.fb-button-right {
    width: 6px;
    background-position: 100% -80px;
    display:inline;
}
```

Also, same for the `fb-button-center`.